# Find a keyword "id" and change its value in inline style

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im having trouble figuring this one out.

```
<div class="large-image" style="visibility: visible; cursor: default; background-image: url("images.sc?previewBinaryDataId=36"); background-position: 50% 50%;">
</div>
```

Im trying to use jquery to change the background image url, by just changing the DataId value

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you not able to take the current inline styles into it's own CSS?  You're referencing a "large-image" class, so I assume you have some sort of sheet.

Comment: no, I'm helping out someone who made a GoDaddy Shop page and it's very limited. So I'm using jquery to add some more functions. I added a thumbnail preview, but now I'm having trouble changing the inline style "background-image: url()" @Handonam

Comment: You could read the whole `style` Attribute into a string and delimiter that String by `;` . After that you could find the array-index starting with "background-image" and simply `str.replace()` the appropriate substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you need a `function` that can be called to change these images? Maybe? Well, here's one:

```
function changeImg(newNum) {
    var div = $('.large-image');
    var parts = div.css('background-image').split('=');
    div.css({
        'background-image': parts[0] + '=' + newNum + '")'
    });
}
```

And you could attach that to an `onClick` or whatever or just call it like so:

```
changeImg(76);
```

That should do the trick, but I'm just guessing as there's no HTML to look over.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your example is right, as you don't have a "dataid" value. Also, you have a double quote that's terminating the styles list (right after `url(`).  Are you hoping to get something such as..

```
<div data-image-url="foo.jpg" id="myDiv">
```

to end up being

```
<div data-image-url="foo.jpg" id="myDiv" style="background-image:url('foo.jpg')">
```

?

If so, then you can do the following

```
var image = $('#myDiv').data('image-url');
$('#myDiv').css("background-image", "url('" + image + "')");
```

**edit:** it looks like you were looking to replace the `previewBinaryDataId` value.  This will retain the image file you're trying to keep (the image.sc)

```
var someNewId = 49
var reg = new RegExp(/(?:previewBinaryDataId=)(\d+)/)
$('#myDiv').css('background-image').replace(reg, 'previewBinaryDataId=' + someNewId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var number = 39;
var backgroundNumber = "url('images.sc?previewBinaryDataId=" + number +"')";
  jQuery('.large-image').css({
    "background-image": backgroundNumber
  });
});
```

If you wanted the DataId field to be dynamic, you would just have to change the number variable to be dynamic.

Here is a link to a working fiddle:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/urxz8zoj/

Hope this helps!